# Method Not Allowed (POST): /password_change_done

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

i am new to django/python

i am trying to change user password but i am getting error

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /password_change_done
Method Not Allowed: /password_change_done
[23/Jul/2020 19:11:05] "POST /password_change_done HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

this is my url patterns just for password changes :

```
 path('password_change',
    auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='password_change.html'),
    name='password_change'),

    path('password_change_done',
    auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_change_done.html'),
    name='password_change_done'),
```

both my html pages for this operation
my html code: password_change

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3> Change Password</h3>
     
    <form action="{% url 'password_change_done' %}" method="POST" class="form-signin">{% csrf_token %}

        <input name="Old password" class="form_control" placeholder="Old password"
        type="password" id=old_password required="true">
        <input name="new password" class="form_control" placeholder="new password"
        type="password" id=new_password required="true">
        <input name="confirm password" class="form_control" placeholder="confirm password"
        type="password" id=confirm_password required="true">
        

        <button  type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my html code for password_chang_done:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <h2> <img src="{% static 'images/welcome.jpg'  %}"> </h2>
    
    <h5>hello,{{request.user.username}}</h5>
    <script>
        window.alert("password sucessfully changed")
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should make the POST request to the `"{% url 'password_change' %}"` view. The `password_change_done` is the result when the change is successul.

Comment: share your password_change_done controller.

Comment: @mursalin: I think these are the ones from `django.contrib.auth.views`, but with an updated template name (in the `.as_view(..)` call).

Comment: changing the post request to password_change keeps me on the same page and it does not redirects me to the next page

Comment: Really, if all you want to do is restyle it using bootstrap4, save yourself [some pain](https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the POST request to the `password_change` endpoint, not the <s>`password_change_done`</s>` endpoint, so:

```
<form action="{% url 'password_change' %}" method="POST" class="form-signin">
    …
</form>
```

In is quite common in Django web development, and in web development in general to make a POST to the same view that first generated the page with a GET request.

Furthermore the `PasswordChangeView` view uses the [**`PasswordChangeForm`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L329-L370):

> ```
> class PasswordChangeForm(SetPasswordForm):
>
>     # …
>
>     field_order = ['old_password', 'new_password1', 'new_password2']
> ```

The name of the `<input>` elements thus should be `old_password`, `new_password1`, and `new_password2`:

```
<input name="old_password" class="form_control" placeholder="Old password" type="password" id=old_password required="true">
<input name="new_password1" class="form_control" placeholder="new password" type="password" id="new_password" required="true">
<input name="new_password2" class="form_control" placeholder="confirm password" type="password" id=confirm_password required="true">
```

Comment: nothing happens when i submit the form. am i missing something very small?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: are you sure the form names are valid? What if you render `{{ form.errors }}` in the template?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: you thus need to specify the name of the `input` elements properly, see edit.